# to store the userID of the friend requests through the sessionID

Tags: php, mysql

i'm developing a social network site where i want to store the 'userID' of the friend requests in a FriendRequest table for a user account. I planned to acquire it using sessionID but i dont know exactly how to get the sessionID.

Comment: show your efford here..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a session after a particular user logged in.

i.e

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = 1001;
```

after doing so, you will have access to this variable and value it holds anywhere with in the application. so you can simply take it and insert in to your table using a very simple query.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Age, SessionId)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35, ".$_SESSION['userID'].")");
```

You will also need to refer these two links to get a basic idea of session handling.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: thanks for the help @mazraara but I got another problem too how can i get the sessionID value? do i have to pass it with the query